# JSON GSON converting from String does not work using nested Objects and Arrays

Tags: json, serialization, gson, deserialization

So I'm already sitting a while on this one. I'm trying to convert this JSON String to a Project Object. (Projekt class as below)

```
String projectEmptyString = "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Seminararbeit Geschichte\",\"description\":\"Der Wilde Westen\",\"comments\":[],\"appointments\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"AppointmentSample\",\"description\":\"AppointmentSample\",\"startDate\":{\"day\":1,\"month\":2,\"year\":2020,\"hour\":4,\"minute\":5},\"endDate\":{\"day\":5,\"hour\":2,\"minute\":1,\"month\":4,\"year\":3},\"type\":\"DEADLINE\"}],\"handlers\":[],\"processors\":[],\"type\":\"SEMINARARBEIT\"}";
```

It does won't work.
I already came to the conclusion that if i set the appointments array empty like this:

```
\"appointments\":[]
```

the conversion works. So there has to be a **fail in deserializing to an Appointment object**.

```
\"appointments\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"AppointmentSample\",\"description\":\"AppointmentSample\",\"startDate\":{\"day\":1,\"month\":2,\"year\":2020,\"hour\":4,\"minute\":5},\"endDate\":{\"day\":5,\"hour\":2,\"minute\":1,\"month\":4,\"year\":3},\"type\":\"DEADLINE\"}]
```

I really would like to know what's GSON's problem here?

Project class:

```
public class Project {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("comments")
    private ArrayList<Comment> comments;
    @SerializedName("appointments")
    private Collection<Appointment> appointments;
    @SerializedName("handlers")
    private Collection<User> handlers;
    @SerializedName("processors")
    private Collection<User> processors;
    @SerializedName("type")
    private ProjectType projectType;

// constructor, getter, setter,...
}
```

Appointment class:

```
public class Appointment {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    @SerializedName("type")
    private AppointmentType appointmentType;

    // constructor, getter, setter,...
}
```

The weird thing is that if i fill e.g. the comments array with data and set the appointments array empty - using the same json structure (I think) - it works just fine. see below:

```
"[{\"id\":1,\"content\":\"Der Wilde Westen war im 19. Jahrhundert!\",\"restricted\":true,\"wasEdited\":false,\"creationTime\":{\"day\":1,\"month\":5,\"year\":2020,\"hour\":12,\"minute\":30},\"author\":{\"id\":1,\"username\":\"LuckyLuke\",\"email\":\"luckyluke@web.de\",\"roles\":[\"ROLE_ADMIN\"],\"userInfo\":{\"id\":1,\"forename\":\"Lucky\",\"surname\":\"Luke\",\"studentNumber\":1234567}}},{\"id\":2,\"content\":\"Cowboys sind ja so doof!\",\"restricted\":false,\"wasEdited\":true,\"creationTime\":{\"day\":3,\"month\":5,\"year\":2020,\"hour\":15,\"minute\":49},\"author\":{\"id\":3,\"username\":\"JackDalton\",\"email\":\"jackdalton@web.de\",\"roles\":[\"ROLE_USER\"],\"userInfo\":{\"id\":3,\"forename\":\"Jack\",\"surname\":\"Dalton\",\"studentNumber\":7654312}}}]"
```

I know, this might be too much input, but I'm really on the edge of despair..

EDIT1:

projectString is shown above

```
Project projekt = newGson().fromJson(projectString, Project.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it by myself.

Apparently, GSON doesn't like Inheritage.
I passed a User's id (User.class) to its subclass UserInfo (UserInfo.class)

I removed the inheritage, now everything works fine..